# zsh completion tag-order matching patterns

Tags: zsh, wildcards, autocomplete

Is it possible to use *matching patterns* instead of `ignored-patters` in `tag-order`?

I'd like to try a custom limited set of matching completions on the first try without a prefix, like this:

```bsh
$ man <Tab>
man info zshall
```

This is a simplified example. I'd like to do the same for git. My current style relies on a specific set of aliases or command arguments to be ignored, which is not ideal:

```bsh
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:git:*' force-list  always
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:git:*' tag-order \
  'main-porcelain-commands:-freq:frequently\ used\ commands aliases'
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:git:*:main-porcelain-commands-freq' \
  ignored-patterns '(am|archive|bisect|bundle|clean|cherry-pick|citool|fetch|gc|gui|ls-files|log|notes|range-diff|show|stash|status|submodule|subtree|worktree)*'
```

which shows:

```bsh
$ git <Tab>
add                -- add file contents to index
ai                 -- alias for 'add --interactive'
amend              -- alias for 'commit --amend --reuse-message=HEAD'
branch             -- list, create, or delete branches
checkout           -- checkout branch or paths to working tree
clone              -- clone repository into new directory
commit             -- record changes to repository
ctags              -- alias for '!.git/hooks/ctags'
describe           -- show most recent tag that is reachable from a commit
df                 -- alias for 'diff --staged'
diff               -- show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc.
format-patch       -- prepare patches for e-mail submission
graph              -- alias for 'log --graph --oneline --decorate'
grep               -- print lines matching a pattern
init               -- create empty git repository or re-initialize an existing one
ls                 -- alias for 'ls-files'
merge              -- join two or more development histories together
mv                 -- move or rename file, directory, or symlink
pull               -- fetch from and merge with another repository or local branch
push               -- update remote refs along with associated objects
rebase             -- forward-port local commits to the updated upstream head
res                -- alias for 'reset --soft HEAD^'
reset              -- reset current HEAD to specified state
revert             -- revert existing commits
rm                 -- remove files from the working tree and from the index
shortlog           -- summarize git log output
st                 -- alias for 'status --short --untracked-files=no'
tag                -- create, list, delete or verify tag object signed with GPG
```

I'd like to know if it is necessary to ignore everything, and then use `fake-always`, or if I could use a negative lookup in `ignored-patterns`, or else if I should write a custom complete function to select few manual pages that are actually on the system and use that custom tag first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a negative lookup in `ignored-patterns`: use a single pattern which uses the [`^` negation operator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators). (`extended_glob` is always enabled during completion, but I recommend `setopt extended_glob` anyway because it's also useful outside of completion.)

```
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:git:*:main-porcelain-commands-freq' \
  ignored-patterns '^(add|branch|…)'
```

Comment: thanks! I was confusing it with `(?!regex)`.